# Draw an horizontal rule under the author name

Tags: beamer, pdftex, posters

in this code what is the code line that draw the horizontal rule under the author.

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\usepackage[scale=1.24]{beamerposter} % Use the beamerposter package for laying out the poster

\usetheme{confposter} % Use the confposter theme supplied with this template

\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=ngreen,bg=white} % Colors of the block titles
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=white} % Colors of the body of blocks
\setbeamercolor{block alerted title}{fg=white,bg=dblue!70} % Colors of the highlighted block titles
\setbeamercolor{block alerted body}{fg=black,bg=dblue!10} % Colors of the body of highlighted blocks
% Many more colors are available for use in beamerthemeconfposter.sty

%-----------------------------------------------------------
% Define the column widths and overall poster size
% To set effective sepwid, onecolwid and twocolwid values, first choose how many columns you want and how much separation you want between columns
% In this template, the separation width chosen is 0.024 of the paper width and a 4-column layout
% onecolwid should therefore be (1-(# of columns+1)*sepwid)/# of columns e.g. (1-(4+1)*0.024)/4 = 0.22
% Set twocolwid to be (2*onecolwid)+sepwid = 0.464
% Set threecolwid to be (3*onecolwid)+2*sepwid = 0.708

\newlength{\sepwid}
\newlength{\onecolwid}
\newlength{\twocolwid}
\newlength{\threecolwid}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{48in} % A0 width: 46.8in
\setlength{\paperheight}{36in} % A0 height: 33.1in
\setlength{\sepwid}{0.024\paperwidth} % Separation width (white space) between columns
\setlength{\onecolwid}{0.22\paperwidth} % Width of one column
\setlength{\twocolwid}{0.464\paperwidth} % Width of two columns
\setlength{\threecolwid}{0.708\paperwidth} % Width of three columns
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.5in} % Reduce the top margin size
%-----------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{graphicx}  % Required for including images

\usepackage{booktabs} % Top and bottom rules for tables

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\title{Consumer Electronics Meetup: From radiation to immersion } % Poster title

\author{matematika.pl} % Author(s)

\institute{2015} % Institution(s)

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\addtobeamertemplate{block end}{}{\vspace*{2ex}} % White space under blocks
\addtobeamertemplate{block alerted end}{}{\vspace*{2ex}} % White space under highlighted (alert) blocks

\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{2ex} % White space under figures
\setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{2ex} % White space under equations

\begin{frame}[t] % The whole poster is enclosed in one beamer frame

\begin{columns}[t] % The whole poster consists of three major columns, the second of which is split into two columns twice - the [t] option aligns each column's content to the top
\begin{column}{\sepwid}

\end{column} % Empty spacer column

\begin{column}{\onecolwid} % The first column

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   OBJECTIVES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{alertblock}{Objectives}
Objectives for today:
\begin{itemize}
\item Introducing specific vocabulary.
\item Quick revision of quadratic function.
\item Factorising Quadratics.
\item Proving Vieta's formulas.
\item Carrying out gained knowledge by working out some word problems.
\end{itemize}

\end{alertblock}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   QUICK REVISION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{block}{Quick Revision}

\textbf{Forms of Quadratic Function}
\begin{itemize}
\item $f(x) = ax^2+bx+c$ is called the \textbf{standard form}.
\item $f(x) = a(x-x_1)(x-x_2)$ is called the \textbf{factored form}, where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the roots of the quadratic function.
\item $f(x) = a(x-h)^2+k$ is called the \textbf{vertex form}.
\end{itemize}

\textbf{Delta $\Delta$}\\*
$\Delta$ determines tells us how many solutions quadratic equation have:
$$\text{number of solutions}=
\begin{cases}
2 &\text{when } \Delta > 0\\
1 &\text{when } \Delta = 0\\
0 &\text{when } \Delta < 0
\end{cases}
$$


\textbf{The Quadratic Formula}
$$x = \frac{-b\pm \sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}$$

\textbf{Graph of Quadratic Function}

\end{block}

%------------------------------------------------

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{1.png}
\caption{Graph of $f(x)=ax^2|_{\{0.1, 0.3, 1.0, 3.0\}}$}
\end{figure}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{column} % End of the first column

\begin{column}{\sepwid}\end{column} % Empty spacer column

\begin{column}{\twocolwid} % Begin a column which is two columns wide (column 2)

\begin{columns}[t,totalwidth=\twocolwid] % Split up the two columns wide column

\begin{column}{\onecolwid}\vspace{-.6in} % The first column within column 2 (column 2.1)

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MATERIALS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{block}{Factorising a Quadratic}

Factorising a quadratic means putting it into two brackets, and is useful if you're trying to draw a graph of a quadratic solve a quadratic equation. It's pretty easy if $a=1$ (in $ax^2+bx+c$ form), but can be a real pain otherwise.
\newline
\newline
In order to factorise a quadratic you should follow steps outlined below:

\begin{enumerate}
\item Rearrange the equation into the standard $ax^2+bx+c$ form.
\item Write down two brackets: $(x\ \ \ )(x\ \ \ )$
\item Find two numbers that multiply to give 'c' and add or subtract to give 'b' (ignoring signs).
\item Put the numbers in brackets and choose their signs.
\end{enumerate}

\end{block}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{column} % End of column 2.1

\begin{column}{\onecolwid}\vspace{-.6in} % The second column within column 2 (column 2.2)

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   P
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{block}{Factorising- Tasks}
1. Factorise $x^2-x-12$.
\[\]
\[\]
\[\]
\[\]
2. Solve $x^2-8=2x$ by factorising.

\end{block}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{column} % End of column 2.2

\end{columns} % End of the split of column 2 - any content after this will now take up 2 columns width

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   IMPORTANT To REMEMBER
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{alertblock}{Myth of Delta $\Delta$}

It's commonly believed that in order to work out roots of a quadratic function you must count $\Delta$ and use other previously established formulas. However this is untrue since factorising in many cases is as good or even better than simply counting $\Delta$.

\end{alertblock} 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{columns}[t,totalwidth=\twocolwid] % Split up the two columns wide column again

\begin{column}{\onecolwid} % The first column within column 2 (column 2.1)

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EXAMPLE OF FACTORISATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{block}{Example of Factorisation}
Solve $x^2+4x-21=0$ by factorising.

$$x^2+4x-21=(x\ \ \ \ \ )(x\ \ \ \ \ )$$
$1$ and $21$ multiply to give $21$ - and add or subtract to give $22$ and $20$.\\*
$3$ and $7$ multiply to give $21$ - and add or subtract to give $10$ and \textbf{$4$}.

$$x^2+4x+21 = (x+7)(x-3)$$

And solving the equation:
$$(x+7)(x-3)=0$$
we get
$$x=-7,\ \ \ x=3$$

\end{block}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{column} % End of column 2.1

\begin{column}{\onecolwid} % The second column within column 2 (column 2.2)

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PROOF OF VIETA'S FORMULAS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{block}{ Proof of Vieta's Formulas}
Let's prove that:
$$x_1 + x_2 = \frac{-b}{a}$$
When $\Delta$ is positive we have two roots:
$$x_1 = \frac{-b-\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a},\ \ \ x_2 = \frac{-b+\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}$$

Substituting for $x_1$ and $x_2$ respectively, we receive:

$$x_1 + x_2 = \frac{-b-\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a} + \frac{-b+\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a} =$$
$$ = \frac{(-b-\sqrt{\Delta}) + (-b+\sqrt{\Delta})}{2a} = \frac{-2b}{2a} = \frac{-b}{a}$$

The same we could do with another pattern, which state that $x_1 x_2 = \frac{c}{a}$, but proving this is going to be your task in next section.

\end{block}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{column} % End of column 2.2

\end{columns} % End of the split of column 2

\end{column} % End of the second column

\begin{column}{\sepwid}\end{column} % Empty spacer column

\begin{column}{\onecolwid} % The third column

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CONCLUSION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{block}{Vieta's Formulas- Task}
1. Prove that $$x_1x_2 = \frac{c}{a}$$
\[\]
\[\]
\[\]
\[\]
\[\]

\end{block}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=red,bg=white} % Change the block title color

\begin{block}{Glossary}

\begin{table}
\vspace{2ex}
\begin{tabular}{l l l l}
\toprule
\textbf{verb} & \textbf{noun} & \textbf{meaning}\\
\midrule
add & addition & $+$ \\
subtract & subtraction & $-$ \\
multiply & multiplication & $\cdot$ \\
divide & division & $\div$ \\
solve & solution & getting answer \\
substitute & substitution & $t=x^2$ \\



\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Word Formation}
\end{table}


\end{block}

\setbeamercolor{block alerted title}{fg=black,bg=norange} % Change the alert block title colors
\setbeamercolor{block alerted body}{fg=black,bg=white} % Change the alert block body colors

\begin{alertblock}{Some Necessary and Useful Vocabulary}

\begin{itemize}
\item (n.) sign $\rightarrow$ $+$ or $-$
\item (n.) equation $\rightarrow something = 0$ 
\item (n.) factor $\rightarrow$ two multiplied factors give result
\item (v.) factorise $\rightarrow$ putting into brackets
\item (n.) coefficient $\rightarrow$ a constant number i.e. $a$, $b$, $c$ in a pattern $ax^2+bx+c$
\item (n.) quadratic function $\rightarrow$ $f(x) = ax^2+bx+c$
\item (n.) root $\rightarrow$ $\sqrt{sth}$ or solution of quadratic equation
\item (n.) formula $=$ pattern
\end{itemize}

\end{alertblock}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{column} % End of the third column

\end{columns} % End of all the columns in the poster

\end{frame} % End of the enclosing frame

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think the macro drawing the line is somewhere in this code, but rather in the theme `beamerthemeconfposter.sty`.

Comment: @campa, great! it is what I thought

Comment: I googled the `sty` file: in the version I found it's line 106 (it's not a rule but rather an empty `beamercolorbox` with dark blue foreground.

Comment: @campa Would you like to write an answer?

Comment: @samcarter Done. Though it's a strange answer, as nothing in the MWE has to do with it `:-/`

Comment: @campa Sometimes strange questions need strange answers :) And as longs as it answers the question ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing in this code causing the line. The "title" is defined by the beamer theme `confposter`, i.e. the file `beamerthemeconfposter.sty`. This is nothing standard, as I've found a few different versions on the internet, but the [first google hit](http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~jiarong/poster/icml12-inferning/styles/beamerthemeconfposter.sty) looks promising: it contains the code

```
%==============================================================================
% build the poster title
%==============================================================================
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
 \leavevmode
  \begin{columns}
   \begin{column}{\linewidth}
    \vskip0.5cm
    \centering
    %\includegraphics[angle=270,width=0.1\paperwidth]{head}\\[1ex]
    \usebeamercolor{title in headline}{\color{fg} \textbf{\LARGE{\inserttitle}}\\[1ex]} 
    \vskip0.2cm
    \usebeamercolor{author in headline}{\color{fg} \Large{\insertauthor}\\[1ex]}
    \usebeamercolor{institute in headline}{\color{fg}\large{\insertinstitute}\\[1ex]}
    \vskip0.8cm
   \end{column}
   \vspace{0.8cm}
  \end{columns}
 \vspace{0.3in}
 \hspace{0.5in}\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=47in,colsep=0.15cm]{cboxb}\end{beamercolorbox}
 \vspace{-0.3in}
}
```

The "rule" is actually the last, empy `beamercolorbox`, whose style `cboxb` is defined a few line above with a black foreground colour and a dark blue background. What appears to be a rule is, in fact, a coloured box without content.